# solving euler series with python

Tags: python, math, discrete-mathematics, eulers-number

`s(i+1) = ((si)^2 + 45) mod 1,000,000,007` this is one series for which my program works fine

```
s = [0,0] 
i = 1 
for i in range(1,5):
    s.append((pow(s[i],2) + 45) % 1000000007)
print s
```

values we are getting here are S = 0, 45, 2070, 4284945, 753524550, 478107844, 894218625 i.e. F(2) = 45, F(4) = 4284990 ..

Now we have F(10^2) = 26365463243, F(10^4) = 2495838522951.

By putting value of F(2) in equation (based on program), I am able to get value for F(4). But not same for  F(10^2) to get value for F(10^4). Any hint for this?

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: I suspect you will have to use BigInteger

Comment: Well, you are just showing the piece of code that is working fine. You should post how you are calculating F(x)

Comment: @Stiffo: I am not getting error, issue is can I apply same logic of F(2) for F(10) ?

Comment: @IvoBeckers: the code snippet is only giving F(x)

Comment: The code generates S not F. notice S(4) = 4284945 and F(4) = 4284990. They are not the same

Comment: Also you seem to do first adding 45 and then squaring it. the exercise says the other way around

Comment: @IvoBeckers: oh sorry, updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84805/discussion-between-puncrazy-and-ivo-beckers).

Answer (score 1):

Giving you hints will be dangerous... the project euler group might not be happy.

But I hope saying something like "Birthday paradox" won't be considered cheating... (anyway this is not even a hint to the best answer).

Enjoy your problem~